# ZeroMQ: Executing request in serial fashion on REQ-Router socket

Tags: multithreading, sockets, zeromq

I have built front end with Router sockets-- that forwards the request to REQ-REP Thread like in example http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:lbbroker. But I have only one worker. So in order to process I need to wait untill REQ socket get free. 
But I cannot figure out a way to wait untill one request has been executed. How to execute multiple request in serial fashion on single worker.

I am open to your suggestions.
Thankx

Comment: Right now I have one way to have a boolean variable return false untill req socket get free from one request so that router could forwards other request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind, I have found the answer, the trick to use dealer-Router instead of REQ-Router at worker threads. It will execute sequentially with queuing your messages :)))

Thankx

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)  Be sure to mark your own answer accepted once the system allows you to do so, so the rest of the community knows that your problem is solved.